# LottieView Vertical Center not working on IOS

Tags: react-native, lottie

I used the LottieView animation as splash screen on my project.
It works well on an Android device, but not an IOS device.
On the IOS simulator, the splash animation does not work vertical center and is cut bottom section.
Is there any other solution for IOS?

This is my animation splash code.

```
<View
   style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.animationContainer}>
     <LottieView
       loop={false}
       style={styles.animation}
       imageAssetsFolder="images"
       source={animationPath}
       autoPlay />
   </View>
</View>

StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0.8,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  animationContainer: {
    alignSelf: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  animation: {
    width: windowSize.width
  }
});
```

Comment: Would you like to specify the height?   `animation: {width: windowSize.width,height: "100%"}`

Comment: @hongdevelop thanks for your response.
I set the height "100%", but It does not work. In this case, the height responsive is correct but the width is small then the device.